Increase request timeout for specific resource endpoint
It looks like I can set a global request timeout using:
quarkus.http.read-timeout

Is there a way to override that on a per-endpoint basis? For example, something like my made up RequestTimeout annotation?
@RequestTimeout("120s")
@GET
@Path("/long-running-get")
public MyData getMyData() {
}


We don't have such a feature currentlym but you can certainly open a  feature request asking for it.

Probably SmallRye Fault Tolerance will help. It works a little bit different (e.g. different exception will be thrown on timeout), but it gives a very powerful solution.
